# How to get column from Azure DevOps using API in PowerBI?

Tags: jquery, json, api, powerbi

I want to get some data from azure dev ops by calling the API in Power BI.

I tried this way in the power BI script:
Get Data - Blank Query:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_apis/wit/workitems/1695")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

It will return this:
[image]

Then I choose New Source - Web
and fill the URL parts with this URL: `https://dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_apis/wit/workitems/1695`

[image]

After that it will return this table:
[image]

My expectation is, I need to get all the `id` columns not only 1 which is `1695` because in my azure dev ops, I also have 100 `id`. Is it possible to get all the `id` and other information without querying them one by one?

I really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you so much

#### Updated

I tried to use get-work items by listing out the work item id like this:

```
https://dev.azure.com/XX/XX/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=1695,1696,1697,1698,1699,1700,1701,1702,1703,1704,1705
```

So if I have more than 300 ids', should I write down all the IDs manually?
Anyone can give an idea, please? Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the [API Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

You need to use [**Work Items - Get Work Items Batch API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#uri-parameters)

**URI Parameters**

```
| Name         | In    | Required | Type   | Description                                                                                      |
|--------------|-------|----------|--------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| organization | path  | True     | string | The name of the Azure DevOps organization.                                                       |
| project      | path  |          | string | Project ID or project name                                                                       |
| api-version  | query | True     | string | Version of the API to use. This should be set to '7.1-preview.1' to use this version of the api. |
```

**Request Body**

```
| Name        | Type                | Description                                                                                              |
|-------------|---------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| $expand     | WorkItemExpand      | The expand parameters for work item attributes. Possible options are { None Relations Fields Links All } |
| asOf        | string              | AsOf UTC date time string                                                                                |
| errorPolicy | WorkItemErrorPolicy | The flag to control error policy in a bulk get work items request. Possible options are {Fail Omit}.     |
| fields      | string[]            | The requested fields                                                                                     |
| ids         | integer[]           | The requested work item ids                                                                              |
```

**Responses**

```
| Name   | Type       | Description          |
|--------|------------|----------------------|
| 200 OK | WorkItem[] | successful operation |
```

**Note:** First-time URL hit will provide you 200 records. But next onward you have to explicitly provide ids as comma separated

So in case you have any further queries then you have to contact their support by creating an account.